# Is it possble to efficiently filter out entities with no value set for a property of type TextProperty in Google Apps Engine? How?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I recently had to update one of my model's properties from type `StringProperty` to `TextProperty` in order to overcome the restrictive limit (a maximum of 500 characters). That wasn't a problem till I realized some of my old queries like:

> SomeEntity.gql('WHERE property1 != :1',None)

where `property1` is a property in the model couldn't work :-(.

The query previously worked, and it did help me to only fetch those entities that had a value set for `property1`.

How can I efficiently obtain the same results in this scenario where the type is `TextProperty`?

Comment: Also note that there's no point using != here: != translates into two queries, one using < and one using >. Since None is the smallest possible value, you may as well just use >.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter or order on a TextProperty. To achieve what you want to do, add a new BooleanProperty 'has_text' and filter on that. Then you just have to be sure to set the BooleanProperty whenever you change the TextProperty.

This solution follows Google App Engine's general convention of pre-computing everything that you want to filter on.

Comment: Surely, this works. I wanted to probe for any un-documented hacks that might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ndb then adding a [ComputedProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed) is often the best way to do any query who's filters can't otherwise be easily expressed. Note that you have to re-put each entity after adding the new property for the index to work (this goes for the boolean property previously recommended as well)